# php, how to call a javascript function?

Tags: php, javascript, gigya

i am trying to use gigya auth properties to login users on my website. They have a function that needs to be called after i authenticate the credentials as seen in this [illustration](http://developers.gigya.com/index.php?title=Template:%7Egs_Authentication_common_implementation)

I have a form and when i submit the form i send it to login.php where i authenticate my users. My question is how do i `call socialize.notifyLogin`?.

this is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var conf = { APIKey:'2_9E9r_ojXEqzZJqKk7mRqvs81LtiSvUmBcm' }; </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var secret = 'eIqtclW2CxC6qvmT55MvOxZ5Rm7V5JhBV/gioJLKIxM=';
var yourSiteUid= '<?php echo $talentnum;?>'; // siteUID should be retrieved from your user management system

function your_b64_hmac_sha1(secret, datePlusSite) { 
var b64Sig = ''; // Place your implementation here ... 
return b64Sig; 
}

function printResponse(response) {
if ( response.errorCode == 0 ) {
    alert('After notifyLogin');    
}
}

var dateStr = getCurrentTime();  
var datePlusSite = dateStr + "_" + yourSiteUid;
var yourSig = your_b64_hmac_sha1(secret, datePlusSite);

var params={
siteUID:yourSiteUid,
timestamp:dateStr,
signature:yourSig,
callback:printResponse
};

gigya.services.socialize.notifyLogin(conf,params);
</script>
```

to be more clear i set the `$talentnum;` inside my login.php. so i have `the form` i send it ti `the login.php` and a `redirect page`... Where the call to `socialize.notifyLogin` will be?

thanks,
any idea helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

If you call login.php as the target of an HTML form, you should redirect the user to a new HTML page upon successful login. This new HTML page should contain the `socialize.notifyLogin` call.

If you call login.php via an AJAX request, you should call `socialize.notifyLogin` in the "success" callback of the AJAX request.

In no case, however, will you be able to execute the Javascript function directly from your PHP script. PHP executes on the server before the Javascript is sent to the user as output with your HTML document, and therefore cannot execute Javascript functions directly.

Comment: for the first option.. you place the code inside an `window.onload = function(){}` or just in the page??

Comment: @Patrioticcow: It depends on what is returned by the call. Does the `notifyLogin` call change something on your page, or does it just ping the external service? In the first case, you will want to execute it when the page has loaded (onload). In the second, it doesn't matter.

Comment: actually the `gigya.services.socialize.notifyLogin(conf,params);` sends some values to the gigya servers. and i would like to see the response function say something: `function printResponse(response) {
    if ( response.errorCode == 0 ) {
        alert('After notifyLogin');    
    }
}`

Comment: Since you want output, you will want to execute the call after the page has fully loaded by using the `onload` event.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed before the page loads, therefore you cannot call a JavaScript function from PHP.